# Send List Type to View from Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Entities:

```
public partial class Institution
{
public int? Id { get; set; }

public string? District { get; set; }

public string? InstitutionCode { get; set; }

public string? InstitutionName { get; set; }

public string? DemolitionStatus { get; set; }

public string? ReinforcementStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
  public class HomeController : Controller
{
    _context c;

    public HomeController(_context c)
    {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
       var GetAll=c.Institutions.ToList();  
        return View(GetAll);
    }
    }
```

In View

```
@model List<GetAll>

   @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

     @item.InstitutionName
    }
```

Also it doesn't work:
The type or namespace name 'GetAll' could not be found

Try with @model SolutionName.Entities or Ienumarable  or adding namespace @using FBMv3.Controllers

What is the wrong or missing?

Comment: How the `Institutions` collection is defined and how the entity of the collection is defined? Include those definitions to the question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try with @model SolutionName.Entities or Ienumarable or adding
> namespace @using FBMv3.Controllers
>
> What is the wrong or missing?

Well, first of all, `GetAll`cannot be a reference for your `Institution` list.
assuming, you are using `asp.net core` application, in this scenario, here `@model List<GetAll>` should be the location of your `Institution` class. For instance if your `Institution` class located like below folder:

[image]

So you should write the code like this `@model IEnumerable<DotNet6MVC.Models.Institution>` instead of `@model List<GetAll>`

**Complete sample for you:**

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {


            var instituteList = new List<Institution>()
            {
                new Institution(){ Id =101,District = "Dis-A", InstitutionCode = "IC-1",InstitutionName = "IN-AAA",DemolitionStatus="YES",ReinforcementStatus = "T"},
                new Institution(){ Id =102,District = "Dis-B", InstitutionCode = "IC-2",InstitutionName = "IN-BBB",DemolitionStatus="NO",ReinforcementStatus = "F"},
                new Institution(){ Id =103,District = "Dis-C", InstitutionCode = "IC-3",InstitutionName = "IN-CCC",DemolitionStatus="NO",ReinforcementStatus = "T"},
                new Institution(){ Id =104,District = "Dis-D", InstitutionCode = "IC-4",InstitutionName = "IN-DDD",DemolitionStatus="NO",ReinforcementStatus = "T"},
                new Institution(){ Id =105,District = "Dis-E", InstitutionCode = "IC-5",InstitutionName = "IN-EEE",DemolitionStatus="YES",ReinforcementStatus = "T"},
               

            };
            return View(instituteList);
        }
```

Note: You could write your controller code as well. Like this:

```
        var GetAll=c.Institutions.ToList();  
        return View(GetAll)
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<DotNet6MVC.Models.Institution>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.District)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InstitutionCode)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InstitutionName)
            </th>
           
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.District)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InstitutionCode)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InstitutionName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="EditMember" class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-memberId="@item.Id">Details</a> |  <a asp-action="EditMember" class="btn btn-warning" asp-route-memberId="@item.Id">Edit</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Note:** Be double confirm in your scenario, it would be `@model IEnumerable<YourProjectName.YourClassFolder.Institution>`. Because, your problem is here.

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** If you still have any concern on this I would highly recommend you to check this [official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-7.0#create-controller-and-views)